# abstract class protected method junit test case

Tags: java, junit

Consider the code:

```
abstract public class TigerFinderPage extends TigerPage
private Manager manager;
protected Manager getTiger()
{
    //  If we haven't already done so,  get the tiger.
    if (tiger== null) {
        try {
            tiger= EntityResolution.getTigerFromName(ResTools.resolveNoTranslation(getConfigBundle(), "tiger", ""));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogTools.error(logger, null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    return tiger;
}
```

TRY 1:

```
public class TigerFinderPageTest {

private TigerFinderPage tigerFinderPage;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    TigerFinderPage = new TigerFinderPage () {
        @Override
        protected ResourceProvider getBundle() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected ResourceProvider getConfigBundle() {
            return null;
        }
    };
}

@Test
public void testTigerManager(){
    assertNull(tigerFinderPage.getTiger());
}
}
```

How Do I test the protected method when they are in different package? I have tried using reflection, but dont know how to implement it in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by `when I do a notNull`? What does `ResTools.resolveNoTranslation` do? It's not clear where you expect the information needed to create a `Tiger` instance to come from.

Comment: `ResTools.resolveNoTranslation` has nothing to do with this, it is just an implementation to convert the manager to spanish language or same.

Comment: If you are trying to test a protected method, Use reflection. Check Here - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html

Comment: Well that's going to be called with `null` as a first argument, given that `getConfigBundle` returns `null`. What do you expect it to do with that? I fail to see how it has "nothing to do with this" when it's part of the code for `getTiger()`. Again, I still don't see where you expect `getTiger()` to get the information from. Even if `resolveNoTranslation` returns something, what does `EntityResolution.getTigerFromName` do in your test environment? Have you debugged through the code in your test?

Comment: You pointed out right. Thanks, Sorry for saying nothing to do with this.

Comment: Well, you are not using ``assertNotNull``, you are using ``assertNull`` which reproducably fails!

Comment: @JonSkeet Nope. After returning the getBundle(), getConfigBundle() also null is being returned.  I would like to mention that they both are in different package.

Comment: Not at all sure what you mean by any of that, by we still don't know what `resolveNoTranslation` is going to return, or what you expect `EntityResolution.getTigeerFromName` to do with whatever it returns. It's not clear which protected method is causing a problem (you appear to have three of them) or what the problem is. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints for suggestions about how to write questions clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing non-public members ties your tests to your implementation and makes it harder to refactor.

If it's significant enough that it can't be tested via the public interface then it must be separate functionality that could live in its own class à la [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

In this case I'd have a separate class and tests for `LazyTigerFactory`:

```
public final class LazyTigerFactory {
    private Manager manager;
    public Manager getTiger()
    {
        //  If we haven't already done so,  get the tiger.
        if (tiger == null) {
            try {
                tiger= EntityResolution.getTigerFromName(ResTools.resolveNoTranslation(getConfigBundle(), "tiger", ""));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogTools.error(logger, null, e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        return tiger;
    }
}
```

Then use it in your class:

```
abstract public class TigerFinderPage extends TigerPage
    private final LazyTigerFactory tigerFactory = new LazyTigerFactory();
    protected Manager getTiger(){
       return tigerFactory.getTiger();
    }
```

## Benefits

- You can get full test coverage around the creation from the factory tests without cluttering your `TigerFinderPage` tests.
- You're free to easily change the `LazyTigerFactory` for another later.
- `TigerFinderPage` has fewer direct dependencies.
- `TigerFinderPage` is smaller, less Lazy/Entity boiler plate cluttering what this class really does (its single responsibility).
- You can even change to inject a factory interface completely decoupling it which may aid other tests.

Answer (score 0):

One answer would be to follow JUnit's best practices and have both the production code and the code to test it **in the same package**, in order to allow accessing `protected` members, but **in different source folders**, so the non-production code doesn't disturb the production code. E.g., in maven's structure:

```
-- src
   +-- main
       +-- java
           +-- org
               +-- mypackage # Production code for org.mypackage
   +-- test
       +-- java
           +-- org
               +-- mypackage # Testing code for org.mypackage
```

If this is not an option, you can inherit from the abstract class and increase the visibility of the said method, just so the test can access it:

```
public class TigerFinderPageTest {        
    public static class TigerFinderPageDummy extends TigerFinderPage {
        @Override
        protected ResourceProvider getBundle() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected ResourceProvider getConfigBundle() {
            return null;
        }

        /** Note this method is PUBLIC */
        @Override
        public Manager getTiger() {
            return super.getTiger();
        }
    }

    private TigerFinderPageDummy tigerFinderPage;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        tigerFinderPage = new TigerFinderPageDummy();
    }

    @Test
    public void testTigerManager(){
        assertNull(tigerFinderPage.getTiger());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a production code and of the same maven structure described by you. But when I do a `assertNotNull(tigerFinderPage.getTiger());` it fails. I have debbuged this method `tigerFinderPage.getTiger()` it return a tigerManagerProxy object.